# Yarn shop with related patterns and multiple color buying

Tags: e-commerce

Hello i was tasked with creating a online yarn shop something like http://www.redheart.com. For them the most important features that they want, are the features to be able to buy multiple different colors of one kind of yarn and they want there to be related free pattern that you can knit with it. So i currently find myself at a loss at what would be the most proper way to do it. What would be the best CMS to use for those features i am a bit experienced with Prestashop and i have done a few shops with it, but i think that the build in add to cart doesn't support to buy multiple colors at the same time and am not sure how i will go about the related patterns. So any ideas and suggestions from anyone more experienced would be appreciated.

Comment: You did not receive attention because, this question is totally opinion based. As always, every dev will call out for his/her favorite framework and you would have no more information at the end. They can all do it, but all requires a different level of expertise. My suggestion would be : if you have expertise in any of those already, go for it or try to get some expertise in the other and make the choice yourself based on what you can get from the different framework.

Comment: And FYI, the site you are giving as example do use a java e-commerce software called [Hybris](http://www.hybris.com)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's an out of box that's going to just do it without some modification.  You can try WooCommerce but I think you're going to need to modify any of the 'out of box' CMSes or themes to do what you want.  You should be able to fairly easily modify the back end to add a second item to the cart with a first.  A possible alternative solution is using Magento and the Wordpress Bridge, as Magento supports this feature.